# Why doesn't validation work after cleaning?

Tags: html, angular

After the adding method: "addPost", the form is cleared and the validation does not work and the add button is active,  it should be active only when the forms are correctly populated. Help please solve the problem

```html
<div class="card" *ngIf="toggleCreate">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" minlength="1" #title/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].invalid && (angForm.controls['title'].dirty || angForm.controls['title'].touched)"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].errors.required">
                    Title is required.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4">Picture Address (url)</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="url" #url pattern="https?://.+"
                       title="Include http://"/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].invalid && (angForm.controls['url'].dirty || angForm.controls['url'].touched)"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
                Address(url) is required.
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].errors.required ">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group but-group">
                <button (click)="addPost(title.value, url.value); title.value=''; url.value=''"
                        [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm correct clearing the form will also remove the validators. If you only want to empty the values use a loop and excute `patchValue('');`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** changing the value of the **FormControls**, just for the elements and changing the values will not resetting the FormGroup to `pristine`.
But since you use the Reactive Forms, why not simply resetting the form? (`angForm.reset()` - https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset).